# How to add an onItemClickListener() in grid View implemented using custom adapter (here i named CategoryAdapter)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter

MainActivity.kt file - this is the main activity.

How to add an `onItemClickListener()` in gridview implemented using a custom adapter (here I named `CategoryAdapter`)? I like to add it to set click listener in the image.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 package com.hari.rideit.Controller

 import android.content.Intent
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.view.MenuItem
 import android.view.View
 import android.widget.AdapterView
 import android.widget.GridView
 import android.widget.Toast
 import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
 import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
 import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
 import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
 import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 import com.hari.rideit.Adapters.CategoryAdapter
 import com.hari.rideit.Adapters.ViewPageAdapter
 import com.hari.rideit.R
 import com.hari.rideit.Services.DataService
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
 import java.util.*

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

 lateinit var adapter:CategoryAdapter
 lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
 lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
 lateinit var navView: NavigationView
 lateinit var gridview:GridView
 internal lateinit var viewPager:ViewPager
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

     drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
     navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
     gridview= findViewById(R.id.contentGridView)

     val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
             this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 0, 0
     )
     drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
     toggle.syncState()
     navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
     adapter= CategoryAdapter(this,DataService.categories)
     gridview.adapter= adapter


     viewPager=findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
     val adapter= ViewPageAdapter(this)
     viewPager.adapter=adapter
 }
```

**Category Adapter**:
this is the custom adapter used to get the image and text in gridview

```
    package com.hari.rideit.Adapters

    import android.content.Context
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import com.hari.rideit.R
    import com.hari.rideit.model.Category

    class CategoryAdapter(context:Context,categories:List<Category>):BaseAdapter(){
    val context= context
    val categories= categories
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val categoryView: View
        categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.category_layout, null)
        val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage)
        val categoryname: TextView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText)
        val category = categories[position]
        categoryname.text = category.title
        val resourceId =
            context.resources.getIdentifier(category.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
        categoryImage.setImageResource(resourceId)
        return categoryView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return categories[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return categories.count()
    }

}
```

Comment: hello Hari, welcome to the StackOverflow communicty. Please make sure to read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, when you want to add to content to about your question, *edit* your question rather than posting an answer in a forum like style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onClickListener to each item of the GridView. Before returning categoryView, set onClickListener on it.

```
categoryView.setOnClickListener { 
        //put your code here
    }
```

If you want to access the clicked position in your MainActivity.kt. Create an Interface in CategoryAdapter class. See the code below.

```
 interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onClick(position:Int)
    }
```

Now pass a variable to CategoryAdapter of type OnItemClickListener.

```
class CategoryAdapter(context:Context,categories:List<Category>, var listener:OnItemClickListener):BaseAdapter(){
 // rest of the code
```

Now before returning. Before return categoryView, set onClickListener on it and pass the position to the listener

```
categoryView.setOnClickListener { 
            listener.onClick(position)
        }
```

Now in your MainActivity.kt file implement OnItemClickListener and override OnClick function.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, CategoryAdapter .OnItemClickListener {

     //rest of the code

   override fun onClick(position:Int){
       // perform the code.
   }


}
```

Comment: but by this way how can i know which image is clicked?

Comment: On which line it is showing the error? The listener.onClick should be same as defined in the interface.

Comment: what to pass when i initialize the adapter?                                             adapter=  CategoryAdapter(this,DataService.categories,)

Comment: pass this to the adapter: `adapter= CategoryAdapter(this,DataService.categories,this)` .

Comment: have you added  CategoryAdapter .OnItemClickListener to your MainActivity.kt like `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, CategoryAdapter .OnItemClickListener {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your adapter constructor to:

```
class CategoryAdapter(context:Context,categories:List<Category>, val listener: View.OnClickListener)
```

And call it from your Activity like this:

```
   adapter= CategoryAdapter(this,DataService.categories, object: View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
```

Inside your adapter, add this code after "categoryImage.setImageResource(resourceId)":

```
categoryImage.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onClick(categoryImage)
        }
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()    context is showing red is it equal to this

Comment: and how to know which image is clicked?

Comment: you need to use the context of your activity: Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Comment: To know the position of your view, you can create a custom listener like this 
interface CustomClickListener {
    fun onClick(position: Int)
}

Answer (score -1):

convertView.setOnClickListener(){}